# Mailgun bounces not triggering webhook

Tags: mailgun

I have webhooks set up for bounces, clicks, opens, failures, and deliveries.

Clicks, opens, and deliveries all work. In my logs I see that I have no red permanent failures, but lots of orange temporary failure events such as 429, 451, 499. Neither the failure nor the bounce webhook has ever been triggered. I know they are set up correctly on my end since the "Test Webhook" link does trigger them in my Mailguin control panel.

Is this expected behavior, ie, are only some bounces, or only after n-tries, does the webhook actually get hit, or is something wrong on my or Mailgun's end?

I'm using the PHP API to send messages, if it matters.